# Normal Random variables

Tags: probability, statistics

A normal random variable $X$ has a mean of $\mu = 8.4$ and a standard deviation of $\sigma = 2$. I am try to compute the following probability to four decimal places:
\begin{equation}
Pr[X ≥ 9] =
\end{equation}

Comment: There is software that will do it for you, and online normal distribution calculators. If you are doing it using tables, use the fact that if $X$ is normal mean $\mu$ standard deviation $\sigma$, then $\Pr(X\ge a)=\Pr(Z\ge (a-\mu)/\sigma)$, where $Z$ is standard normal.

Answer (score 1):

We can say that
\begin{equation}
Pr[x \geq 9] = 1 - Pr[x < 9].
\end{equation}
We can compute the latter probability using the normal distribution's cumulative distribution function so that
\begin{equation}
Pr[x < 9] = \Phi\left(\frac{9 - \mu}{\sigma}\right) = \Phi\left(\frac{0.6}{2}\right) = \Phi(0.3) \approx 0.6179.
\end{equation}
Then
\begin{equation}
Pr[X \geq 9] = 1 - 0.6179 = 0.3821.
\end{equation}